# How to post variable with onclick in form

Tags: php, javascript

```
<form action='#' method='post' onclick=' ConfirmChoice(); 
return false;' style='display:inline-block;'>
<input type='hidden' name='delete_dish' value='" . $row['dishname'] . "'>
<input type='image' src='images/delete2.png' alt='Submit' name='delete2' value='delete2'>
</form>
```

Everytime I `$_POST` on another file, it says `Notice: Undefined index: delete_dish`

But, when I remove `onclick=' ConfirmChoice(); return false;` and put `FILENAME.php` instead of #, it works.

Comment: please write your question clearly, what you want is not known from this question

Comment: you need to post all you related code or we won't be able to help with such a small description of your problem.

Comment: sorry im new here, i posted the code, but i wont show up. im getting confused

Comment: I'm trying to $_POST on a different file, but whenever the form has a "onclick" on it, the next file won't recognize the value od delete_dish :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You aren't making a POST request at all

From one of your comments (confirm message changed for brevity):

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    <!-- Confirm Dialog Box for deletion --> 
    function ConfirmChoice() { 
        answer = confirm("Are you sure?")
        if (answer !=0) { 
            location = "recipe7.php" 
        }
    } 
</script>
```

*Assuming* that `location` means `document.location`: This will mean given how it's used in the question, that as soon as a user clicks on anything in the *form* only one of two things will happen:

- Nothing
- User is redirected to `recipe7.php`

### Working solution

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    function ConfirmChoice() { 
        return confirm("Are you sure?");
    }
</script>
<form action='recipe7.php' method='post' onsubmit='return ConfirmChoice();' >
    <input type='hidden' name='delete_dish' value='" . $row['dishname'] . "'>
    <input type='image' src='images/delete2.png' alt='Submit' name='delete2' value='delete2'>
</form>
```

The two differences are:

- Make the form submit to where it's supposed to submit
- Use onsubmit to prompt the user, not on click.

If a form onsubmit callback returns falsey - submitting the form is aborted.

### Additional points

#### Comments in javascript

are of the form:

```
// this is a comment
/* this is a 
multiline
comment */
```

Using html comments (`<!-- asdf -->`) in a javascript block is not valid.

#### Make things work without js *by default*.

Writing functionality that only works with js enabled when it's not necessary - just adds complexity. Instead make it work without js - and then add whatever js functionality you want (the minimum) to it afterwards.

Sticking to this principle will have two concequences:

- Js logic is simpler (because there's less of it)
- If there's a js error things *still work*.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
onclick=' ConfirmChoice(); return false;'
```

to

```
onclick='return ConfirmChoice();'
```

Try this one....

```
<form name='myform' action='recipe7.php' method='post' onclick=' ConfirmChoice(); 
return false;' style='display:inline-block;'>                
function ConfirmChoice()
{
  var r = confirm("Are you sure?");
  if(r == true)
  {
    document.myform.submit();
     return true;
  } 
  else
  {
     // do something
     return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I just did that, but now it won't go to the next file

Comment: write your code here ConfirmChoice() { }

Comment: <script language="javascript"> <!-- Confirm Dialog Box for deletion -->

    function ConfirmChoice()

    {

     answer = confirm("Are you really sure you want to delete this dish?\n\nYou will not be able to retrieve the dish again once it is deleted. Press OK to continue and CANCEL otherwise.")

     if (answer !=0)

     {

      location = "recipe7.php"

     }

    }

  </script>

Comment: Sorry btw, I dont know how to format a code in comment D:

Comment: please refer this page for submit in function http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Comment: <form name='myform' action='recipe7.php' method='post' onclick=' ConfirmChoice(); 
return false;' style='display:inline-block;'>                function ConfirmChoice()
{
  var r = confirm("Are you sure?");
  if(r == true)
  {
    document.myform.submit();
     return true;
  } else {
     // do something
     return false;}